# what does "crack the formula" means?

Tags: grammar

What does it take to be happy?
The Nordic countries seem to have it all figured out.
Finland and Denmark have consistently topped the United
Nations' most prestigious index, the World Happiness
Report, in all six areas of life satisfaction.
How have they **cracked the formula**?
And, are the people they are really the happiest?

-=====================

what does "crack the formula" means?

Comment: There's a mistake in the last sentence. It should probably read, "*And, are the people **there** really the happiest?*"

Comment: Also, have you looked up the words "crack" and "formula" in a dictionary?

Comment: It means "solved the problem".

Answer (score 1):

When you are trying to solve a difficult problem or mystery, and you finally succeed, you can say that you have cracked the problem, just like cracking open the shell of a nut in order to be able to eat the nut.  "Cracking the case" is an especially common expression in detective stories and crime investigations, for example.

(And just as a side note, since this is ELL I'll mention as well that there is no *s* at the end of *does mean*).

Comment: ... maybe also explain what formula means in this context?